# How to communicate between two django instances?

Tags: python, django, websocket, backend, django-channels

So I am having two connections, one is a websockets connection with the frontend for notifications and another is a http connection which the user will directly use to perform some special actions. So there will be a websocket connection from one tab and a separate http connection in another tab. I have to relay events happening in the django http instance to the websockets connection so it can notify the frontend. Now as I understand Django, it creates separate application instances for every request. I want a way to quickly communicate that http instance and the websockets instance.
I'm using Django (version 2.2) along with django-channels for the websocket functionality. I know that there is a `CHANNEL_LAYER` feature in channels to communicate over something like Redis. I'm avoiding the use of Redis because this would be the only use-case for it and it won't be feasible. Is there another way to achieve this without the use of Redis?

Comment: Well, think of it. You have two Python processes running. How else can you easily exchange data between the processes except through some external service like the Channel layer through Redis? That is already enough reason to use a channel layer.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I'm also curious to know about specific external services other than Redis. Like I was looking into Amazon SNS/SQS which are cheaper than Redis for production.

Comment: There are currently no channel layers built on top of those services. Unless you want to build one yourself. The Redis channel layer is actually a separate library from Channels itself. So you can build a similar library to the Redis channel layer which uses those services. But it isn't a trivial work. So you have to choose between the cost and the ease of building a custom channel layer